# 10.04 LTS next release after 2.6.32-57-server

Tags: release-management

We'll be soon doing a kernel upgrade of a lot of boxes running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 2.6.32-57-server. Because we have a patched driver as part of the setup we are interested in the release date of the next kernel release after 57.
Thanks
Paul

Comment: Close voters Ubuntu Server 10.04 is not **EOL**. Support expires on 04-2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next kernel will be [2.6.32-58.120](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kernel-sru-workflow/+bug/1300852) and will soon be in -proposed.

Once proposed, the testing week will begin and if no regresssions are found after this week it'll be released.

So in approximately 10 days.

Visit https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/kernel-sru-workflow for further details about the different SRU tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for the release date of the next .57 kernel. I found the following:

**Ubuntu Packages** - http://packages.ubuntu.com/

**Kernel 2.6.32-57**

- Generic - http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/admin/linux-image-2.6.32-57-generic
- Generic-PAE - http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/linux-image-2.6.32-57-generic-pae
- Server - http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/admin/linux-image-2.6.32-57-server
- Changelog - http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_2.6.32-57.119/changelog

**Kernel 2.6.32-58+** (Pre-Release / Test Kernels)

https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa

Is this what you wanted?